# Python 3 Regular expression Lease DHCP

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-re

I have the following information in the DHCP leased file

```
lease 201.249.14.226 { 
  starts epoch 1586469086; # Thu Apr 09 17:51:26 2020
  ends epoch 1587765086; # Fri Apr 24 17:51:26 2020
  tstp epoch 1587765086; # Fri Apr 24 17:51:26 2020
  cltt epoch 1586469086; # Thu Apr 09 17:51:26 2020
  binding state free;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet f8:d1:11:50:1c:2b;
  set vendor-class-identifier = "MSFT 5.0";
  client-hostname "TL-MR3420";
}
lease 201.249.11.68 {
  starts epoch 1586469229; # Thu Apr 09 17:53:49 2020
  ends epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  tstp epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  cltt epoch 1586469440; # Thu Apr 09 17:57:20 2020
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;
  option agent.circuit-id "mil-bras-06--172.26.22.237 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.32";
  client-hostname "ZTE";
}
lease 201.249.11.199 {
  starts epoch 1586469229; # Thu Apr 09 17:53:49 2020
  ends epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  tstp epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  cltt epoch 1586469440; # Thu Apr 09 17:57:20 2020
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;
  option agent.circuit-id "cnt-bras-07--172.26.220.225 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.20";
  client-hostname "ZTE";
}
```

is a reduced sample

I need to get after applying Python re
if and only if "binding state active;"

the next:

```
lease 201.249.11.68
binding state active;
hardware ethernet 34: 4d: ea: fa: 9d: 10;
option agent.circuit-id "mil-bras-06--172.26.22.237 trunk 0/1/0/2: 427.32";
client-hostname "ZTE";

lease 201.249.11.199
binding state active;
hardware ethernet 34: 4d: ea: fa: 9d: 10;
option agent.circuit-id "cnt-bras-07--172.26.220.225 trunk 0/1/0/2: 427.20";
client-hostname "ZTE";
```

It is not mandatory to use the python module (regular expressions)
I don't know if there are better ideas or alternatives

I am doing this ...

```
import re
with open('/var/lib/dhcp.leases', 'r') as f:
    #pattern = re.compile(r'((option agent.circuit-id)\s"(\w{3}-\w{4}-\d{2}\W{2}))')
    #pattern = re.compile(r'(\W{2}((\d{0,3}).(\d{0,3}).(\d{0,3}).(\d{0,3})\s\w{5}\s[0-9/]{7}:\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}"))')(
    #pattern = re.compile(r'(lease [0-9.]+)')
    #pattern = re.compile(r'binding state active;')
    #pattern = re.compile(r'(hardware ethernet).(\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2})')
    #pattern = re.compile(r'(option agent.circuit-id)\s["]+(\w{3}-\w{4}-\d{2}\W{2}\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}.*?)')
    contents = f.read()
    matches = pattern.finditer(contents)
    for match in matches:
        print(match)
```

I have several individual patterns to find the results
but I don't know how to put them together fulfilling the conditional

If and only if "binding state active;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` here, with a regex pattern which targets and captures the desired text:

```py
matches = re.findall(r'(lease \d+(?:\.\d+){3}) \{[^}]+(binding state active;)[^}]+(hardware[^}]+option[^}]+client[^;]+)', inp)
output = ['\n'.join(x) for x in matches]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['lease 201.249.11.68\nbinding state active;\nhardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;\n  option agent.circuit-id "mil-bras-06--172.26.22.237 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.32";\n  client-hostname "ZTE"',
 'lease 201.249.11.199\nbinding state active;\nhardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;\n  option agent.circuit-id "cnt-bras-07--172.26.220.225 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.20";\n  client-hostname "ZTE"']
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Please elaborate on what you don't know.  In my answer above, simply read your text file into the `inp` variable, and then use my code.

Comment: Working, 
Thanks Tim

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk (since you mentioned python is not required), as follows (1 line is out of order but that can be fixed):

```
Mac_3.2.57$# save lease line;  if bind active, print lease line and active line;  look for other lines and print iff bind is active (finding } logically DE-acivates); plus some format
Mac_3.2.57$cat input.txt | awk '{if($1=="lease"){L=$0;sub(/{/,"",L)};if($0~/ *binding state active; */){print L;f=1};if($0!~/ *next binding state free; */&&$0!~/ *rewind binding state free; */&&$0!~/ *} */&&f==1){print $0};if($0~/ *} */){f=0};if(f==2){print $0}}'
lease 201.249.11.68 
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;
  option agent.circuit-id "mil-bras-06--172.26.22.237 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.32";
  client-hostname "ZTE";
lease 201.249.11.199 
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;
  option agent.circuit-id "cnt-bras-07--172.26.220.225 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.20";
  client-hostname "ZTE";
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$cat input.txt 
lease 201.249.14.226 { 
  starts epoch 1586469086; # Thu Apr 09 17:51:26 2020
  ends epoch 1587765086; # Fri Apr 24 17:51:26 2020
  tstp epoch 1587765086; # Fri Apr 24 17:51:26 2020
  cltt epoch 1586469086; # Thu Apr 09 17:51:26 2020
  binding state free;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet f8:d1:11:50:1c:2b;
  set vendor-class-identifier = "MSFT 5.0";
  client-hostname "TL-MR3420";
}
lease 201.249.11.68 {
  starts epoch 1586469229; # Thu Apr 09 17:53:49 2020
  ends epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  tstp epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  cltt epoch 1586469440; # Thu Apr 09 17:57:20 2020
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;
  option agent.circuit-id "mil-bras-06--172.26.22.237 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.32";
  client-hostname "ZTE";
}
lease 201.249.11.199 {
  starts epoch 1586469229; # Thu Apr 09 17:53:49 2020
  ends epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  tstp epoch 1587765229; # Fri Apr 24 17:53:49 2020
  cltt epoch 1586469440; # Thu Apr 09 17:57:20 2020
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 34:4d:ea:fa:9d:10;
  option agent.circuit-id "cnt-bras-07--172.26.220.225 trunk 0/1/0/2:427.20";
  client-hostname "ZTE";
}
Mac_3.2.57$
```